# Sheets formula to decrement a value by x% n times applied

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a value in google sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eGmweV5MqyGAU7dWSw28WgPso0mszP3DrsJ51oA-RbQ/copy

It needs to be decremented by x% successively n times

For example

value = 100
x = 2%
n = 3

Expected value = 94.1192

Because

1. 100 - (2% of 100) = 98
2. 98 - (2% of 98) = 96.04
3. 96.04 - (2% of 96.04) = 94.1192

I have tried with

=REPT(100,3*0.02)

I have no idea how to find this out using google sheets formula

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
=reduce(B1,sequence(B3),lambda(a,c,a-(a*B2)))
```